# Foxx/ArangoDB: Can you create a response that adhere to JSON API specification?

Tags: arangodb, json-api, foxx

I am currently writing some micro services with Foxx to be consumed by Ember.js. Ember data plays very nicely with JSON API (http://jsonapi.org) responses. So I tried to serialize the Foxx responses with the json-api-serializer (https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-api-serializer) - but with no luck. I only found the forClient method, but this only allows me to operate on the JSON representation of single objects, not the whole response. So my question: Is it possible to implement JSON API with Foxx/ArangoDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return arbitrary responses from Foxx routes, so it's entirely possible to generate JSON responses that conform to JSON API.

However there's no built-in way to do this automatically.

I don't see anything in `json-api-serializer` that shouldn't work in Foxx, so I'm not sure what problems you are encountering. You should be able to simply return the output object with `res.json(outputFromSerializer)` and set the content type with `res.set('content-type', 'application/vnd.api+json')`.

If everything else fails you can just write your own helper functions to generate the boilerplate and metadata JSON API expects.

Comment: OK, you are right. My problem was that I've fiddled around in the model's forClient method instead of implementing the serialization directly in the route. In the route it works like a charm. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!